# How to change the button on the app store to say GET instead of the price? (Allow user to create account before IAP)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just launched my first app on the IOS App Store:) I noticed that the newly released app page on the app store is requiring users to purchase the app before downloading it, how do I change the set up in app store connect to allow users to download the app before purchasing their subscription?

So right now the button where it supposed to say GET is just showing the price of the app and requiring users to purchase. Is it something i'm missing on the Pricing and Availability tab, maybe does it need to include a free option there? Any advice would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find any info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the price to zero (i.e. move it to the free tier) on the Pricing and Availability tab in App Store Connect and the button will say "GET", so the users will be able to download the app for free.

This however will not automatically mean that your users will be able to make in-app purchases in your app, you have to configure IAP products separately (and submit them for review alongside an application build for the first time) and write code to handle the purchases as well as to provide a UI that enables that.

Comment: There's certainly a lag time, give it an hour or so.